# Flink, how to set parallelism properly when using multiple Kafka source?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I still cannot get a clear idea of parallelism, let's say we have a flink cluster which has enough slots. In our flink job, we consume 3 kafka topics from 3 different kafka clusters, each topic has 10 partitions.

If we want to consume the message as soon as possible. What should the parallelism be?

If we set parallelism to 10, then 10 slots will be used, this means, according to my understanding, 10 threads right? If these 10 threads "connect" to the topic_1, then there's no thread reading topic_2 and topic_3.

If we set parallelism to 30, then there're 30 threads, but will these 30 threads be smart enough that 10 of them go to topic_1, and 10 of them go to topic_2, and the rest 10 go to topic_3?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Kafka Consumer groups**

Each Kafka consumer belongs to a consumer group i.e. it can be thought of as a logical container/namespace for a bunch of consumers. A consumer group can receive messages from one or more topics. Instances in a consumer group can receive messages from zero, one or more partitions within each topic (depending on the number of partitions and consumer instances)

[image]

**How are Kafka partitions assigned to Flink workers?**

In Kafka, each consumer from the same consumer group gets assigned one or more partitions. Note that it is not possible for two consumers to consume from the same partition. The number of Flink consumers depends on the Flink parallelism, meaning that each Flink Task (We roughly consider each Flink Task = Flink slots = Flink Parallelism = Available CPU core) can act as a separate consumer in a consumer group. Also, you should notice that topics are just an abstraction for grouping partitions and data, internally only partitions are assigned to Flink’s parallel task instances according to the following pattern.

**There are three possible cases:**

*1. kafka partitions == flink parallelism*

This case is ideal since each consumer takes care of one partition. If your messages are balanced between partitions, the work will be evenly spread across Flink operators

*2. kafka partitions < flink parallelism*

When there are more Flink tasks than Kafka partitions, some of the Flink consumers will just idle, not reading any data:

[image]

In this case, where you have higher parallelism than the number of partitions
(because you want to make use of it in a future operator), you could do a `.rebalance()` after the Kafka source. This makes sure that all operators after the Kafka source get an even load, at the cost of having to redistribute the data (so there is de/serialization + network overhead).

*3. kafka partitions > flink parallelism*

When there are more Kafka partitions than Flink tasks, Flink consumer instances will subscribe to multiple partitions at the same time:

[image]

In all cases, Flink will optimally assign Tasks to the partitions.

In your case, you can create the Kafka Consumer group using Flink Kafka connector and assign one or more topics to it (using Regex, for example). So if Kafka has three topics including 10 partitions each, assigning 30 slots (core) to Flink Job Manager, you can achieve the ideal case, meaning each consumer(Flink slot) will consume one Kafka partition.

Refrences:
[1](https://riptutorial.com/apache-flink/example/27996/kafka-partitions-and-flink-parallelism), [2](https://simplydistributed.wordpress.com/2016/11/29/scaling-out-with-kafka-consumer-groups/), [3](https://www.ververica.com/blog/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to)

Comment: Hi, currently, I'm using one single group.id for all 3 topics, does it matter?

Comment: Thank you. So in my case, set parallelism to 30, flink will "assign" exactly one partition to one slot, right? This sounds pretty smart to me :)

Comment: Yes, just set parallelism to the number of partitions!

Comment: Are you reffering to StreamExecutionEnvironment.setParalellism? Because the comments state that this value is only for Datastream operators. It doesn't mention anything for sources. (for flink 1.9 at least)